# OpenVPN on OpenWRT fails to connect "connection timeout"

Tags: openvpn, openwrt

It seems very elegant to be able to connect to your homenetwork from any public accesspoint without being worried to disclose your traffic. So dispite my lack of computer network experience, and after creating a dyndns for MYDOMAIN.com -- which seems to work fine --, I've tried to install an OpenVPN server via the [official OpenWRT indications](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/vpn/openvpn/server)

However I cannot connect from a external network due to "*connection timeout*". The single indicator of a problem I've observed while configuring, is the

```
Warning: Section 'wan' cannot resolve device of network "<MY-WIFI-SSID>"
```

message while executing the [firewall section](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/vpn/openvpn/server#firewall).

Could you please help to pinpoint the problem where to look for issues, and eventually to solve it?

Comment: Does your OpenWRT have public IP address? (Check it's WAN address, if it isn't one of IANA RFC1918 or RFC6598, you're lucky.) Is OpenVPN running (listening to configured port)? Do you have a firewall rule which permits access to that port from internet?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov: Thank you. It should have a public IP. It is updated by a dyn-dns inside OpenWRT -- it is an IPv4. How can I check if it's one of RFC1918 or RFC6598? ... I don't konw if it"s listening on a port. I've only added this [instructions][https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/vpn/openvpn/server] inclusive the firewall ones. Actually I've tried to see if there is some firewall exceptions, however, i don't really know how to check it effectively. Last time i've experimented with my fireawall I had to reinstall the whole system (TP-Link Archer A7 router)

Comment: Please note this site is about managing information techonolgy at work; home user questions should be asked on the SuperUser. And anyway questions must show at least a bit of understanding of concepts and familiarity with equipment and software. Please, before implementing VPN become a little more accustomised with the network technologies.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov: Thank you for the advice. As far as we consider the description this Q&A site is about: *build[ing] a library of detailed answers to every question about server, networking, or related infrastructure administration.* see https://serverfault.com/tour
On my part. I try to build a network for creating a site in order to start a small business. So If you are open for help, thank you.